# Python Selenium Click on buttons that doesn't have any tags/names/etc

Tags: python, selenium

What's the easiest way to click the buttons bellow ?

```
<input type="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Apply filter">
```

Right now, i am telling selenium to click on specific locations on the screen. In fact, it's not the best deal, because sometimes the buttons change position because of ads.

I also tried with external libraries, like pyautogui, but didn't really find any 'click' solution.

Is there a better way to detect and `.click()` those buttons ?

Comment: My best bet would to use an XPath. `//input[@value="Apply filter"]` or `//input[@type="submit"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no. of ways to inspect the button, in your case the element just have two attributes `type` and `value`. So you may simply use the xpath to inspect the button.
Some xpaths that can be made for this element can be :

```
//input[@value='Apply Filter']
//input[@type='submit']
//input[text()='Apply Filter']
```